# Yii2 put request FormData parse body

Tags: php, yii2, updates, multipartform-data, put

I'm using yii2 for my back end stack and I'm developing a Rest Project.
I have an action which response to http PUT request and the request content-type is form-data and the reason is obvious cause it contains file .

but I can't get request body parsed.
I know this is php bug and it's not related to yii2.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815

and also I've read the following page

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/12466

but it seems that this patch is on master branch only and its not stable yet.

```
-- host: ubuntu 14.04
-- webserver : php internal web server
-- php : PHP 5.5.9
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the patch is not released yet.
Modify the `composer.json` in your project and require `"yiisoft/yii2": "*@dev"` to get unstable version right now. Otherwise just wait for a week or two and we will bump 2.0.10 release with this update

Comment: if it's really one or two week I prefer to work with stable version.
thanks.